# make a shared library from a standlone program - what to do with "int main()"?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

In my program, I need to call a subprocess *sub_prog*.  I do this with a system call, e.g. `system("sub_prog arg1 arg2...");`. Simple enough; all works correctly.

Unfortunately the supercomputer I am using does not support the spawning of subprocess (due to the architecture, you can't use fork(), popen() etc. with MPI.  It's just a fact.).  So the solution would be to make *sub_prog* a (shared) library and call it as a library function, rather than as a sub-process.

I created the shared library *libsub_prog.so* fine.  The problem is - the function I want to call is *sub_prog* itself, i.e., I want to call `main(argc,argv)` of `sub_prog`.

Questions regarding shared libraries usually center around calling member functions from shared libraries.  But what if I want to call the **main** function itself?

(I thought about renaming *sub_prog*'s `int main` to another name, essentially turning its `main` into just another member function.  But there are several global variables deefined right before `int main`).  Would I have to put these in a header globals.h and go in and manually insert "#include globals.h" in every source file?)

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using `dlsym`?

Comment: This is out of scope of std c++ so add the respective tag for your environment.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with renaming main to something else; you seem to have some misconception regarding global variables, your concerns don't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Also, are you sure you need a shared library? There are valid reasons, but you haven't provided any. It might be enough to rename the main function of sub_prog and then simply link both programs together statically.

Comment: I was looking to make a shared library because eventually I will have >= 2 separate programs that call this subprocess, so it would be more appropriate/mature to make a shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just turn it into a normal function by giving it a different name, and call it from the main executable using this new name. If you declare the function to have `extern "C"` linkage, it should be easy to locate the function at runtime using `dlsym`. As to the global variables, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: just leave the global variables exposed above the renamed "main"?  Why wouldn't I need to mannually include them in all other source files?

Comment: On second thought - it is even necessary to rename the `main` function of the sub-process?

Comment: @CycoMatto Certainly never seen a shared lib with 'main' function in it, but if it's not loaded by linker at application start (conflicting symbols), then I guess it should work. Nice way of blocking loading lib at application start, if you ever need one ;) And if you take effort and make your 'main' in the main application not-exported, then it will even work for startup-libs.